# Maven failsafe:integration-test fails to recognize single integration test

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I've been able to get Maven's failsafe module to successfully detect and run the tests in integration test files for dummy projects ([link to GitHub repo](https://github.com/afreymiller/maven-integration-testing)). However, when I try to do the same thing for a module within an existing project, I get an error saying that no tests were executed.

Here's my `pom.xml` for the module in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <parent>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <groupId>DOMAIN</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </parent>

     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <groupId><DOMAIN></groupId>
     <artifactId>aws-service-utilities</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>jar</packaging>

     <!-- Dependencies omitted, pretty sure they're irrelevant to this issue -->

     <build>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.22.0</version>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>integration-test</goal>
                              <goal>verify</goal>
                          </goals>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
       </build>
    </project>
```

Here is the integration test I'm trying to get detected:

**YahooParserIT.java**

```
package com.<DOMAIN>.tests;

import org.junit.Test;
/* Omitting some unnecessary imports */
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;

@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({S3AsyncClient.class, AmazonS3ClientBuilder.class, AmazonS3.class})
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class YahooParserIT {

    @Before
    public void before() {
        TestSetupUtils.prepareS3ServiceUtil();
    }

    @Test
    public void testParser() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(1 == 1);
    }
}
```

I run the command `mvn -Dit.test=YahooParserIT failsafe:integration-test -e` at the level of the aws-service-utilities module and get the following output:

[image]

The above command works perfectly on the dummy project I mentioned in the first sentence of this question. Any idea why it's not detecting the single integration test?

Dropbox link to pom.xml for the entire project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8emcyu63g2isq0/pom.xml?dl=0

Comment: Did you try to execute single test with package prefix for your class `mvn -Dit.test=com.<DOMAIN>.tests.YahooParserIT failsafe:integration-test` ?

Comment: Just tried that, exact same output

Comment: It looks like you are mixing JUnit 3 (extends TestCase) and JUnit 4+ cause you are using `@Test` and `@Before` ...furthermore you don't have a dependency on JUnit in your pom file?furthermore have you located your test in the correct location `src/test/java`?

Comment: @khmarbaise I verified in the parent project's pom.xml file uses JUnit 5, and copied that dependency into the relevant child's pom.xml for good measure. Imports statements are now fully using JUnit5 with the test classes reflecting that too. Still getting same results so far, will verify the correct location and update as necessary.

Comment: Can you please show the pom file which contains the configuration for JUnit 5 and surefire/failsafe configuration....

Comment: @khmarbaise added a Dropbox link at the very end of the question

Comment: In your toplevel pom, surefire and failsafe have to go in pluginManagement, not plugin (for the children to inherit). The children should declare them in plugin (not pluginManagement), artifactId and groupId only. Can you test this change and then report back?